# Why would one use html5 canvas to draw an image instead of using <img>?

Tags: html, html5-canvas

I was going over [a tutorial on html5 canvas](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/tutorials/html5-canvas-images/). One of the sections is teaching you how to draw canvas based on an image. While everything works out fine, I am puzzled about why using canvas over simply loading the image using `<img>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Games which use sprites,
3D games with textured-polygons,
Image-editing functionality,
Cropping and scaling in real-time,
Image-filters in real-time...

If you're ***just*** using canvas to load an image, that's going to be a lot of work for absolutely no payoff, because you actually have to ***LOAD an image into an `img` element, or an `Image()` object, before you can even use it on the canvas***.

Answer (score 3):

You could do image manipulation to the original in this way: think Instagram-style filters or ChromaKey (green-screen).